# Install mailparse on Debian GNU/Linux 9

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

Dear all  got following error while installing Laravel 5.3 project:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser 2.11.1 -> satisfiable by php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser[2.11.1].
    - php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser 2.11.1 requires ext-mailparse * -> the requested PHP extension mailparse is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
```

My OS is Debian:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Here is my PHP version

```
PHP 7.1.30 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2019 03:14:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.30, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install php-mailparse ; phpenmod mailparse` ? You might need to restart apache too.

Comment: Hi mate, I use PECL instead and it fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Hi finally I got the answer, here is my script:

```
pecl install mailparse
```

and then put it on ini file

```
echo 'extension=mailparse.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mailparse.ini;
```

Now just restart everything php-fpm, web server etc.